# Different Title formats for different Terminal apps?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, window-title

I use a script which either activates an already running window of a program, or starts that program if it is not running.  It uses different shortcut-keys; one for each of my most used apps — it checks for a unique window title format.   This has worked fine, until today, when I decided to use `terminator` along side of `gnome-terminal`.

These two terminal apps display the same title format, and I don't know how to change them independently (actually I don't know how to change them at all).

I also use `konsole` (because it displays Unicode better than gnome-terminal), and it has a *profile-option* which allows changes to the *tab-title format* which is mirrored in the window's title,  but `terminator` and `gnome-terminal` don't have this option.

Is there some way to have different title formats for different terminals?

Answer (score 1):

From the shell side, you could look at the shell's parent process and include that in the title somehow:

```
ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$)
```

Or from your script, you might be able to use the window's class attribute which is the third column:

```
wmctrl -x -l
```

If you share the script you're using I might be able to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Yes, thaks.. I already do something very similar to validate marginal/ambiguous cases, and I did think of doing it for this case, but if there is some way to simply change the title bar, I'd prefer that... and also, it would just be handy *to know how to* change the formats... This is what I currently use `pgrep -f -x -n -c  "$procMask"` .. and for the title, its: `wmctrl -l |grep "$windMask" ...`

Comment: Re 'sharing the script'.. The main issue for me here is "How can I change the actual default title formats in a *Terminal window*?".. this is because my approach has been Window-title centric.. I have a script which gives me all Window-IDs for a given regex TitleMask (`window-get-id-by-title-mask`), and then I can use another script: `window-get-exe-by-id` .. but I haven't, as yet, set my main script to handle the situation described in my question... This raised the issue of: Can Terminal-window titles be changed on a per Terminal-program basis? .. thanks for the offer though :)